# Who are the owner of bitfunder.com and btc trading corp?

Tags: exchanges

Do we know who he is? How do we knows he won't run away with our money?

Currently, you can buy their shares both on [BitFunder](https://bitfunder.com/asset/G.ASICMINER-PT) and [BTC Trading Corp](https://btct.co/security/ASICMINER-PT).

Okay cool. But can I trust those 2 companies? Bitfunder and BTC Trading Corp? What about if they run with my money. Who are they? Do we know their real name?

This is not distributed stock exchange. Some guys control it and that some guys may be assholes.

Comment: Do you have account on Paypal? What if they run away with our money? This is the world of internet, all you have is people with fake names. No-one can tell you whom to trust.

Comment: The owner of glbse is james. What about if paypal run away with my money? Paypal is a publicly listed company. Governments know the CEO and stuff. Not sure about bitfunder. Do they have incentives not to run?

Comment: Why on Earth should this be closed? That's a perfectly legit question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitFunder is an exchange that facilitates the trading of "assets" which  include cyber equities such as ASICMINER.

So purchasing shares is engaging in a trade with another party that is selling shares.  BitFunder simply escrows the bitcoins in an exchange account.

BitFunder provides a [method](https://bitfunder.com/assetlist) to claim ownership of shares should the service be forced to close or should the operator simply disappear.

Comment: I see. If the owner disappear as long as asicminer still recoqnize me as a stock owner I still own the stock. And I can trust asictminer. Good enough. Very good. What about BTCTrading Corp.

Answer (score 2):

With BTCT.CO each asset issuer receives a full list of all shareholders holdings every twelve hours.  So if the site did go down the damage would be limited.  Also you should only keep just enough coins for your orders on the site and not use it to store coins long term.